# Different behaviors calling a WCF server side method through its WinForm or through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, methods, call

I’m writing a program that needs a “double” UI: the first one is a classic windows form, the second one through windows phone device. I’m working with WCF (asynchronous, the only possibility with this device), but I’ve got a behavior that appears very strange to me. Well, I’m very basic with WCF, so maybe I’m doing something wrong. I wrote a simpler version of my WCF server code, so the problem here is clearer:

```
[ServiceContract]
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int x = 0;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prova1();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x++;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    void prova1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("x = " + x.ToString());
    }
```

If I click button2 and then button1 I evidently get a popbox with “x = 1”. But if I call prova1() through windows phone app I’ll always get “x = 0”. It is a very general behavior: If I instantiate an object in WCF server’s code and try to use it in a WCF  server’s method called trough the external device, I’ll get an null reference exception. It seems that everything I do in the WCF server code is totally invisible within the methods called trough WCF. There’s a way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `prova1`from the class itself you are working in a program context within windows Forms. This will make the `MessageBox` static methods available to you and you can get the `Show` method to display a pop up.

But when you make the server call from WP7 you are accessing the class from a completely other  application context, so even if the `MethodBox.Show` had worked, it would have displayed the message box on the server, not on the phone. But WCF does not prepare the class for running in an application context and the entire `Show` method fails.

So you are confusing the server/client-scenario involving WP7 and hosted WCF service with the single program context of the Windows Forms app.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer! But… maybe I was not clear… I’m preparing a second user interface, so the user can click the button without needing to sit at the computer running the WF application. In this example, I exactly want that MessageBox shows its pop up just on the server. WP7 is used only to remote control the application. Moreover, instead a MessageBox I can use

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(x.ToString())

 or set a breakpoint and check the x value, during the debug process, and obtaining the same result.

Comment: Hey Stefano - sorry for any midunderstandings :)

Comment: WCF is not intended for UI and it will make your code cluttered with if statements if you proceed with the plan to make a combined implementation. I would go for inheritance or composition.